# Function to fill combo boxes with specific data does not work for more than 1 combo box at a time,no clear errors

Tags: c#, function, combobox

I have a function that is supposed to fill in combo-boxes with its given data. Currently it only works for one combo-box at a time .

I have tried  copying the same function twice(basically I just changed the variable names and made a new function to use with the 2nd combo-box) to see if it was a variable error but it still doesn't work. I rebuilt the solution but it still doesn't work.

this is the code for the function

```
public void FillComboBox(String displayMember, String valueMember, ComboBox combo, String table)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        InitializeComponent();
        string str = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\B8328\source\repos\KaihatsuEnshuu\KaihatsuEnshuu\OI21Database1.accdb";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(str);
        string sql1 = "SELECT "+ displayMember +  "  , "+valueMember+ " FROM "+ table ;
        MessageBox.Show(sql1); //Check Query String

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql1, con);

        da.Fill(dt);

        combo.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
        combo.DisplayMember = displayMember;
        combo.ValueMember = valueMember;


        con.Close();

    }
```

and this is the code im using on the form

```
    public NewOrderForm()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        FillComboBox("customerName", "customerId", comboBox2, "customers");
        FillComboBox("empname", "empno", comboBox1, "emp");
    }
```

I'm expecting both combo boxes in my form to have an array of values to choose from but its always just one that shows the values(the one which was ran first  so in this case the customer combobox).

Comment: If you reverse the order of the two `FillComboBox` calls, what happens?

Comment: the one which was first doesnt get displayed and the 2nd one (which is now the first one to be executed ) has its values displayed.

Comment: I suspect you want to comment out the `InitializeComponent();` call **inside** `FillComboBox`.

Comment: You were right @mjwills  , Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I only had to comment out the InitializeComponent inside hte FillCombobox , thanks @mjwills for the comment!

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //InitializeComponent();
    string str = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\B8328\source\repos\KaihatsuEnshuu\KaihatsuEnshuu\OI21Database1.accdb";
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(str);
```